# Main for openGL code

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to find out how to run this OpenGL code to see the output. How do I write a simple main for this code?

```
 void draw()
    {
    glColor(1,0,0);
    glPushMatrix();
    glScale(3,3,3);
    glTranslate(2,0,0);
    glRotate(90, 0,0,1);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslate(1,0,0);
    drawSquare();
    glColor(0,1,0);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslate(4,0,0);
    glScale(0.5,0.5,0.5);
    glRotate(270, 0,0,1);
    drawSquare();
    }
    void drawSquare()
    {
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex(0,0,0);
    glVertex(0,1,0);
    glVertex(1,1,0);
    glVertex(1,0,0);
    glEnd();
    }
```

Comment: You should read some introductory material on OpenGL. `main()` is not the most relevant concern here, but you will need a drawable and an OpenGL context so that your GL calls have something to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As derhass has pointed out you need access to an opengl context and I also strongly recommend reading up on introductory opengl. I have found the easiest approach for newcomers is to use the GLUT library as it is platform independent, has good documentation and is simple to implement. Good luck!